# compare/check two tables data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help with check data. I have two table. I want to check if file_name in `tableA` is included in content in `tableB`. If not then result is which `file_name` is this.

```
select * from tableA;
| id | file_name
+---+----------
|  1 | apple.jpg 
|  2 | green_apple.jpg
|  3 | red_apple.jpg
|  4 | apple1.jpg
|  5 | apple-juce.jpg

////////////////////////////////////////////

select * from tableB;

| id |  title   |content 
+----+----------+--------
|  1 |  title1  | <img style="border:1px dotted;width:463px;height:611px;margin-left:20px;float:right;padding:3px;" src="image/green_apple.jpg" /><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply <b>dummy text</b> of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
|  2 |  title2  | <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply <b>dummy text</b> of the printing and typesetting industry. </p><img style="border:1px dotted;width:463px;" src="image/apple.jpg" />
|  3 |  title3  | <img style="border:1px dotted;width:463px;" src="image/apple.jpg" /><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply <b>dummy text</b> of the printing and typesetting industry. </p><img style="border:1px dotted;width:463px;" src="image/apple.jpg" />
|  4 |  title4  | <img style="border:1px dotted;width:463px;" src="image/red_apple.jpg" /><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply <b>dummy text</b> of the printing and typesetting industry. </p><img style="border:1px dotted;width:463px;" src="image/apple.jpg" />
|  5 |  title5  | <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply <b>dummy text</b> of the printing and typesetting industry. </p><img style="border:1px dotted;width:463px;" src="image/apple1.jpg" />
```

Comment: question is bit unclear  can you explain what exactly are you comparing  .The content of file_ name column in table A included in file_name of TABLE B  ??/

Comment: Could you add the expected result to your question, please?

Comment: I hate to say this, but what you are asking is not how a database should be used. Since you tagged question with PHP tag too, you should do the comparison using PHP, not MySQL because your data isn't modelled right to do it easily from MySQL. Comparison via PHP should be really trivial using strpos or regexps.

Comment: @Ravindra Shekhawat: I want to found all file_name in tableA which is not included in content from tableB

Comment: @hsan: Result: apple-juce.jpg   because apple-juce.jpg is not in content (tableB).

Answer (score 2):

Exectly i cant get what u want.. But this query may help u..

First You have file name in tableA and that filename is included in content in tableB. So first you have search that if that name is exists or not... after that you can use NOT IN to select data which you want if not exists in tableB..

```
    "select file_name from tableA where file_name like '%$search%' 
    AND file_name NOT IN (select content from tableB where file_name like '%$search%'); 
    ";
```

Comment: I try this and result are: MySQL returned an empty result set. Do you have any idea

Comment: let me know what u r using As $search?

Comment: I try with apple-juce.jpg and apple.jpg, and result is the same. But I have for about 1500 file_names to check.